# What are some of the benefits of understanding differential geometry?

Tags: differential-geometry, gauge-theory, soft-question, education

This question isn't as well-defined as I would like, but here goes.

I'm interested in gauge theory, e.g., Aharonov-Bohm effect, the Berry phase, etc, and I have seen that this can be formulated rigorously in the context of holonomy in differential geometry. However, is there any substantial benefit in formulating it this way, other than it being rigorous? For example, is there some concept/effect that is very difficult to understand unless I know the details of differential geometry. Or maybe is there something that becomes trivial once I understand differential geometry? Examples would be greatly appreciated.

I understand the non-rigorous approach to explaining such phenomena and have some background in (real) manifold theory, but since a lot of gauge theory is formulated in terms of principal fibre bundles and complex manifolds with hermitian metrics, it's quite a learning curve and I'm not sure if it's worth delving into full rigor.

Comment: My diff geometry and analogous physics is not that great, but i think math differential geometry and physics like gauge theory are formulated differently. They look at it differently, that i would think from physics, differential geometry will not be effective at a normal superficial level, weather the relations will very deep mathematical. So it kind of like math definitions of integrals and derivative with limits, for physics but a lot more complicated. And it is not readily useful per say to physics. You know not to differentiate but physics is scientific and concerned with emperical law

Comment: I guess to be short and to point, math looks at things with different motives then physicist. While they can work together on highest levels, the differences are by no means trivial for anyone. Is it useful, yes, but that doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a classic tradeoff in research-level physics. A more sophisticated approach can often

(a) *explain* otherwise mysterious results,

(b) provide an *invariant* formulation that does not depend on arbitrary choices of coordinates, and

(c) *suggest* new directions and connections that are not obvious.

If you are a student, then learning "standard" tools in your field is also important, even if there is some up front cost, because ultimately you will need to have a new idea and so you have to know the "standard" ideas people in your field will know to try. But, it is also often not strictly necessary to use sophisticated new tools. And it is also certainly possible to invest in learning a new tool, and then find it does not give you a good return for your (time and effort) investment. I also personally have the opinion -- probably not shared by everyone -- that differential geometry applied to gauge theories helps elucidate mathematical aspects of Yang-Mills theory, but doesn't add *physical* insight (I also have the same opinion about GR, that differential geometry gives us a nice mathematical understanding but not a physical one -- this is a viewpoint advocated in Weinberg's textbook, but again is not a universally held opinion). Of course you have to learn differential geometry to do GR, and parts of research involving gauge theory, but you should just know *why* you are learning it.

Anyway, the point of this rant is that I'm not going to say whether it is or is not worth learning differential geometry, because I don't know your field, your level, or background, or your goals. On top of that, there is a wide range of what one might mean by differential geometry, from "hardcore" (fiber bundles, holonomy groups) that is fairly specialized, to "vanilla" differential geometry (connections, Lie algebra, differential forms) which basically every working field theorist needs to know. (And that's not even getting into "very hardcore" topics like twistor theory). But I can give an example of (a), (b), and (c):

(a) Differential geometry can *explain* results in gauge theory. A magnetic monopole can exist because it's not always possible to find a globally defined smooth vector potential on the surface of a sphere.

(b) Berry's phase can be understood in an *invariant* way as a geometric phase which does not depend on a specific path. The generality is very clear from the geometric formulation, but it might be less obvious if one only looks at specific examples that have to be calculated on a case-by-case basis.

(c) Differential geometry can *suggest* new directions. Instantons are a major topic in modern gauge theory, and a lot of the language needed to classify and understand these solutions is based on differential geometry.

In the comments, @ChiralAnamoly mentioned a beautiful application to chiral anomalies that is too nice not to bring up. One of the most remarkable results in mathematical physics in the second half of the 20th century is the [Atiyah-Singer index theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atiyah%E2%80%93Singer_index_theorem), which relates the global topology of a manifold to its local geometry, making essential use of the Dirac operator defined on this manifold. Besides its mathematical interest, this result can be used to give a very elegant [derivation of the chiral anomaly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fujikawa_method), which is a result showing that a chiral symmetry present in the classical Lagrangian is broken at the quantum level. Again, this result *can* be derived using "standard" methods by computing certain 1-loop diagrams, but differential geometry provides a deeper understanding of what is going on.

Comment: Nice answer (+1). My only complaint is that you forgot to mention chiral anomalies. ;)

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly That is too nice not to bring up so I added a paragraph :)

Comment: I would say thanks to reading your answer, that diff geometry is good up to the point that calculations and operations performed, make sense and basically the math is correct. An analogy would be limits, convergent series, not really useful to physicist, but then when using finite/numerical approximations, how do we know that mathematically these results are real, well using math we can prove they converge to the continuous case etc. So there is small cases for strait mathematics views, but these aren't every day, and then you can always take a trip to the math department and have them check

Comment: @marshalcraft I think overall that is a fine analogy -- not necessarily important for calculations, but crucial for understanding some of the patterns behind those calculations. There are some specialized cases, though, where differential geometry really is the tool you need to do the calculation -- such as when studying instantons or anamolies in a general context.

Answer (score 6):

I like your question a lot, and this is isn't an answer but it made me think of something Douglas Stanford said on the awesome podcast ["the universe speaks in numbers"](https://podcasts.apple.com/gb/podcast/universe-speaks-in-numbers-douglas-stanford-pedro-vieira/id1479389232?i=1000453027118). (timestamp around 23 minutes)

Stanford was working on a problem and was able to compute some complicated result - he believed the answer, however he had no satisfying explanation as to why he got the answer that he did. He then encountered Ed Witten and after chatting about his result, Witten explained to him how to understand the problem using "fancy mathematics" (what mathematics this means is not specified in the podcast, but knowing who Witten is, it probably was a geometrical insight).

What Stanford said about this is interesting and amusing: he said this was "some simple problem that he cared about" and he thought this should have nothing to do with any fancy mathematics naively. But Witten showed him that day that the fancy mathematics provided the "right" way to derive his result.

I've always wondered what that problem was, and how the fancy math (probably geometry) simplified that Standford's calculation. And your question made me think of that, so here's some food for thought. Again, this is not an answer but maybe someone reading this may know about the specifics of the above problem and this can prompt an answer.

Comment: I strongly suspect Stanford was referring to how Ed Witten knew about Mirzakhani's work on the volume of moduli spaces of something or other, see here https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.03363

Comment: This question actually made me think of the same anecdote :)